# Searchable Dropdown in Asp.net mvc 4

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to implement searchable dropdown list. I have found below link and trying to implement the same.

http://developmentpassion.blogspot.in/2014/01/searchable-dropdown-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html

I am able to get the dropdown but not searchable.

Can someone assist me  how can I get the searchable dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC?

Thanks,
Balu

Comment: "Chosen" seems to be a good solution. It is also not specifically dependent on ASP.NET MVC, but usable by any web technology. Have you included the corresponding JS files?

Comment: Please show some of your relevant code.

Comment: Hi Marcel, I have included the relevant JS files and Below is my code.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1Z7d8OTSWR4YWdXa1ZIX3lYcEU

Answer (score 1):

Please find the given below solution using bootstrap and jquery which can be implemented dynamically later on using asp.net

http://codepen.io/Rio517/pen/NPLbpP

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <h2>Bootstrap-select example</h2>
  <p>This uses <a href="http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/">http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/</a></p>
  <hr />
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
    <option data-subtext="Rep California">Tom Foolery</option>
    <option data-subtext="Sen California">Bill Gordon</option>
    <option data-subtext="Sen Massacusetts">Elizabeth Warren</option>
    <option data-subtext="Rep Alabama">Mario Flores</option>
    <option data-subtext="Rep Alaska">Don Young</option>
    <option data-subtext="Rep California" disabled="disabled">Marvin Martinez</option>
  </select>
  <span class="help-inline">With <code>data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true"</code>. Try searching for california</span>
</div>
```

List of libraries to be used..

//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js

Comment: For better understanding you may also refer to https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/9abm0hhy/

Comment: Thank you Gurmeet Singh. I will try from my end and let you know.

Comment: @Balu no problem do let me know if you face any issues

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CustomsSelect/jquery-customselect.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

$(function () {
    $("#Group_Country").change(function () {
        var options = {};

        options.url = "/Admin/GetCity";
        options.type = "POST";
        options.data = JSON.stringify({ country: $("#Group_Country").val() });
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        options.success = function (data) {
            $("#Group_City").empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var opt = data[i].split('-');
                $("#Group_City").append("<option value=" + opt[0] + ">" + opt[1] + "</option>");
            }
            $("#Group_City").customselect("destroy"); // this is the binding mechanisam
            $("#Group_City").customselect(); // this is the binding mechanisam
        };
        options.error = function () { $("#Group_Country").focus(); };
        $.ajax(options);

    });


@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Group_City, list, new { @class = "custom-select" })
```

this the is the whole process i used to achieve the searchable dropdown

Comment: Hi Arun, Thank you for your comment. However, I am not calling any AJAX service to get the data. I will pass the data from the controller to view. Can you please check the link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1Z7d8OTSWR4YWdXa1ZIX3lYcEU

Comment: you can modify it anyway you want, this is a good method if you have lots of data, all data doesn't needed to be loaded at first, this is an overall